# plotting data with x1, y1, x2, y2 in the same figure - matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to do a Hertzsprung-Russell diagram like this one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:HRDiagram.png 
I have 4 different types of data for the same point (lets call it x1, y1, x2, y2) and i want to put it all together in the same graph, showing 4 axis (2 of them bottom and left as usual and the other 2 top and right).
My code:

```
filename = 'Hipparcos_stars2.xlsx';
sheet1 = 1;

xHRcolor = 'G2:G19920'; 
yHRmag = 'I2:I19920'; 
xHRtemp = 'J2:J19920';
yHRlum = 'K2:K19920';
HRx_c = xlsread(filename, sheet1, xHRcolor); % x1
HRy_m = xlsread(filename, sheet1, yHRmag); % y1
HRx_t = xlsread(filename, sheet1, xHRtemp); % x2
HRy_l = xlsread(filename, sheet1, yHRlum); % y2

figure(1)
ax1 = gca;
line(HRx_c,HRy_m, 'LineStyle', 'o', 'Color', 'k', 'MarkerSize', 1);
set(ax1,'ydir','reverse');

ax2 = axes('Position',get(ax1,'Position'),...
           'XAxisLocation','top',...
           'YAxisLocation','right');
line(HRx_t,log10(HRy_l),'LineStyle', 'o','Color','k','MarkerSize', 1,'Parent',ax2);
set(ax2,'xdir','reverse');

xlabel(ax1,'B-V color')
ylabel(ax1,'V Magnitude')
xlabel(ax2,'Temperature [ºK]')
ylabel(ax2,'Luminosity [log(L/Ls)]')
```

Like this i end up with a figure with 4 axis but with wrong information about the second set of axis. The thing is, with this code, it does not adapt the second set of axis to the data, and for any point i choose, it presents right values of x2 and y2 but wrong values of x1 and y1.
Any idea of how to do something like in wikipedia?
Thanks in advance

for Hipparcos_stars2.xlsx: http://www1.datafilehost.com/d/7d652c04

Comment: Your question is NOT MATLAB related. It is a problem of scaling in astronomic units (I cannot help here). For anyone to see what is going on try next code:

`subplot(211)
line(HRx_c,HRy_m, 'LineStyle', 'o', 'Color', 'k', 'MarkerSize', 1);
set(gca,'ydir','reverse');
subplot(212)
line(HRx_t,log(HRy_l),'LineStyle', 'o','Color','k','MarkerSize', 1);
set(gca,'xdir','reverse');`

Comment: If you google you can find: http://www.princeton.edu/~rvdb/images/NJP/HRdiagMatlab.html. There is some MATLAB code and the conversion is not simply `log10()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`plotyy()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html) and then customize the appearance:

```
h = plotyy(HRx_c,HRy_m,HRx_t,HRy_l,'plot','semilogy')
set(h(1),'ydir','reverse');
set(h(2),'xdir','reverse');
```

Comment: hello! thanks for your response but i need two x axes and 2 y axes. plotyy just makes 2 y axes.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Here the documentation shows [Using multiple x and y axes](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/creating_plots/using-multiple-x-and-y-axes.html) which is what Amro has in his answer.

Comment: yes, that's what i have in my code. the thing is that that code is good for when you have 2 sets of data, and want to plot it in the same graph. that way it shows two lines one in respect to one axes and the other in respect to the second axes. but i have just one set of data with 4 types of information.

Comment: @IrisBreda You need to plot everything against the first axis, overlay the second axis, set manually the x-ticks and y-ticks of the second axis.

Comment: hello Oleg! thank you so much for your help. can you tell me more/less the code to do that? if you check in the HR diagram in wikipedia, the 1st x axis doesn't present a linear relation over the second x axis. it is possible to do that with x-ticks? thank you again for your time.

Comment: Can you provide sample data, add a link to pastebin in your post maybe?

Comment: here it is Oleg! thank you so much for your time: http://www1.datafilehost.com/d/7d652c04

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code with slight modifications to make it work:

```
%# some random data
x1 = linspace(0,1,100);
y1 = exp(x1) .* cos(x1);
x2 = linspace(10,100,100);
y2 = cumsum(rand(size(x2))-0.5);

%# plot
figure
hAx(1) = axes('YDir','reverse', 'XColor','b', 'YColor','b');
hAx(2) = axes('Position',get(hAx(1),'Position'), 'XDir','reverse', ...
    'XAxisLocation','top', 'YAxisLocation','right', 'Color','none', ...
    'XColor','r', 'YColor','r');
linkprop(hAx, 'Position');
line(x1,y1, 'Color','b', 'LineStyle','none', 'Marker','o', 'MarkerSize',2, ...
    'Parent',hAx(1));
line(x2,y2, 'Color','r', 'LineStyle','none', 'Marker','.', 'MarkerSize',5, ...
    'Parent',hAx(2));
xlabel(hAx(1), 'B-V color')
ylabel(hAx(1), 'V Magnitude')
xlabel(hAx(2), 'Temperature [ºK]')
ylabel(hAx(2), 'Luminosity [log(L/Ls)]')
```

[image: screenshot]

Note that the second axis is made transparent by setting its color property to `'none'`. Also the correct way of drawing a scatter of points is to set the line property to `'none'` while specifying the marker using `'Marker'` property.

Also note the use of `linkprop` to link the position property of both axes, that way if one is changed, the other follows.

Comment: hey! :) thanks for your response, but i still doesn't work properly. like this it shows 2 sets of data, one "attached" to the blue axes and other to the red axis. i need to plot just one set of data, "attached" to the 4 axis simultaneously, since each point has information about all the 4 axis.

Comment: yes I intentionally set two different colors to show that there is only 2 axes above. I'm not sure what 4 axes you refer to..

Comment: yes :) every point have 4 types of info. check: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:HRDiagram.png

Comment: each point in that plot have information about color, magnitude, temperature and luminosity. it's like, if you choose one point in that figure you can know its color, magnitude, temperature and luminosity just by checking it's coordinates in each of the 4 axis.

Comment: i'm not sure this is a valid way to visualize multi-dimensional data, since you are mapping 4-dims to x/y locations. For example how would you represent two points differing only in one value, say (1,1,1,1) and (1,1,1,99)? unless the dimensions are actually dependent (i.e `dim3 = a*dim1 + b` for some constants)... Have you considered using another type of visualization like [parallel coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates)?

Comment: the dimensions are dependent of each other, yes, for example, the temperature is a 3rd order polynomial equation of the color. i thought about doing other ways, but the truth is, astronomers are used to that kind of visualization, that's way i wanted to do like that...

Comment: astronomy is not my domain, so I might be missing something.. Do you know the actual equations with which dimensions are related? I'm assuming you have two free ones, and the other two each depending on one of the first two. In other words the data is 2D, the other two dimensions are redundant I guess..